# New CSS3 selectors doesn't work for me?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Ok, I have code like this:

```
<div id="header"> (yeah, have to use div instead of header tag, don't ask me why)
     <a href="link"><img src="image1.png" alt="image1" /></a>
     <a href="link"><img src="image2.png" alt="image2" /></a>
     <a href="link"><img src="image3.png" alt="image3" /></a>
</div>
```

And I want to select the first image after div (first link image) and two last links in css.

I know I could do it by nth-child or first/last child selectors. But I want to use "+" and "~". But they doesn't seem to work!

For example:

```
#header + a {
     border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Gives border to... Nothing!

This one also doesn't seem to work:

```
#header a + img {
     border: solid 1px red;
}
```

What's wrong?

Same effect with "~". Tested in all major browsers....

Comment: `+` is not new to CSS3 (but `~` is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it wrong. The selector you're looking for is

```
#header > a:first-child
```

This will select the first anchor that are direct decedent of `#header`. The `>` is the direct decedent selector, while `:first-child` gets you the... well, first child. To get the image, you would need

```
#header > a:first-child > img
```

The direct decendent selector is not supported in IE6. You can choose not to use it if there are no non-direct decedents you would not want to select, like with the structure you have above, which doesn't have any other anchors other than the ones you want to select.

The `+` is the adjacent sibling selector: http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html. The following HTML structure is what you would need for your selector to work:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<a href="#"><img src="somewhere" alt="" /></a> <-- Selects this one for #header + a
<a href="#"><img src="somewhere" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="somewhere" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Dam! You're right. Sorry! :) BTW do I have to use ">" everywhere? Because "#header a" should work almost the same as "#header > a". I know in the first case inheritance is "deeper", but that's not a problem in this, flat anyway, code?

Comment: @fomicz Well, if it's only one level, then no. If you can drop IE6 support, then you should try to use that as much as possible, in my opinion.